# extjs 4 - toolbox type window (thin border, no title)?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm trying my hands on extjs 4 by trying to recreate some component I have in an old extjs 2 project.

One of the component was creating a floating toolbox (like you get with photoshop) with a thin border and no title or min/max/close buttons. Like so..

[image: in ext 2]

In ext4 , I can't seem to be able to reproduce that same result. Here's what the same code looks like in ext 4:

[image: in ext 4]

This is the code I had:

```
app.Toolbox = Ext.extend(Ext.Window, {  

    ,initComponent : function()
    {

        Ext.apply(this,{
            closable:false,
            border:false,
            width:345, 
            height:60,
            onEsc:Ext.emptyFn,
            resizable:false,
            x:20,
            y:20,
            items:[
                /* icons (a html items) */
            ]
        });

        app.Toolbox.superclass.initComponent.call(this, arguments);

    }

    /* handlers, methods, etc */

});
```

Is there any way to get a similar result in ext 4?

I tried using some css to hide some elements like the title bar, but ext 4 always calculates the height of the window as if the element was visible, which looks even weirder.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ext.panel.Header is just an extended Ext.container.Container so you can do as you wish to it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I like the idea.. how can I manipulate the header/container in order to obtain the visual aspect I want?

Comment: How does one get the header instance from a window or panel?

Comment: Aaaah, interesting.. panel has a preventHeader config that can be set to true, that prevents the window header from being drawn..

Answer (score 2):

I think the closest you're going to get is by applying `frame: true` which kind of forces the content to fill the window frame.

However, it doesn't seem to work if you have a Close button in the top right.

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    height: 60,
    width: 345,
    closable: false,
    layout: 'fit',
    frame: true,
    items: {
        html: '<p>hello</p>'
    }
}).show();
```

You're still going to have to style it a little, but its far closer to what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's better than what I'm getting. The main issue now is it's making the toolbox very hard to move because the border area is really hard to grab..

Comment: Also, in addition to your sample code, I needed to add shadow:false otherwise ext will miscalculate the size of the shadow around the box..